# Badge List url syntax to Interactive grid with Filter applied

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm trying to link to a interactive grid from a Badge list item and apply a filter based on the APP_USER.

Here is my current syntax which gets me to the page but no filter is applied.

```
'f?p='||:APP_ID||':6:'||:APP_SESSION||':IR:RIR,CIR:::ig_m_id:'||:APP_USER|| ':' as link,
```

I have the static_id of my IG set to `IR` and the static_id of the field that I'm try to filter to `m_id`.

The link takes to page 6 but no filter is applied to the IG.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/htmdb/linking-to-interactive-grid-reports.html#GUID-B794775D-A5EE-4D82-A829-83E79E95F165